# Controlling an omnidirectional robot like pr2 in ROS Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am fairly new to ROS and Gazebo and I apologize if this question seems easy in advance.

So, I basically want to implement a path planning algorithm by simulating a scenario in "ROS-Gazebo" and I am using "ROS Hydro-Gazebo 1.9" distributions. My algorithm assumes that the robot is omni-directional i.e., it can move in both x and y coordinates, independently. As I have found out, "pr2" and "care-o-bot" are two robots that offer omni-directional motion. The only feature that I need from them is the omni-directional wheels and other features such as laser, arm, etc. are not needed. I would also need to get the odometry data.

Problem: I am not aware of any control plugin or library to control and move the "pr2" in "ROS Hydro-Gazebo 1.9". I am able to bring up the "pr2" in "Gazebo" using "roslaunch" command. But I cannot control it and move it around. To give an idea of what I want, in another case I am able to control a pioneer2dx using a differential drive controller plugin (libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so). I wonder if such a thing exists for "pr2". If not, is there any other solutions to my problem?

I would greatly appreciate any helps towards finding a solution for my problem.

Thanks,

Ali

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/138426/controlling-an-omnidirectional-robot-like-pr2-in-ros-hydro/) by [alimohandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/3776/alimohandes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The PR2 simulation and the real PR2 can be controlled by publishing a geometry_msgs/Twist to the /cmd_vel ROS topic. This is a fairly standard topic for controlling mobile bases in ROS.

You can generate simple teleop command on cmd_vel using the teleop_twist_keyboard package, or you can do more complex teleop specific to the PR2 using the pr2_teleop package.

I suspect that the gazebo plugin that simulates the PR2 base is more complicated than you're interested in. If you haven't already, it may be worth asking on the gazebo answers site.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1